# Accesses array of structure members with structure in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} abc;

typedef struct {
    abc c;
} xyz;

int main() {
   abc ss[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
   xyz cc[] = { ss };
   return 0;
}
```

Hi I want to print the value '5`using the structure variable`cc`?
I tried many ways but I failed to do so.

Comment: `{ss};` : `ss` evaluted to `abc*`, not `abc`.

Comment: The struct abc has 3 members but you pass 6 members to the initialization list. And why are you using arrays with 1 item? You don't print anything anywhere. Post the complete code.

Comment: [this](http://ideone.com/apiR2X) ?

Comment: I don't see any attempt to print a value here.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `main` function to :

```
int main()
{
    abc ss[]={ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
    xyz cc[]={ss[0], ss[1]};
    return 0;
}
```

Which will do the following :

**1.** Create array `ss` with two `abc` structs inside it. Each one will get three values for its fields.

**2.** Create array `cc` with two `xyz` structs inside it. Each one will contain an `abc` struct.

Now if you want to print `5`, use the following statement:

```
printf("%d\n", cc[1].c.b);
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It seems to have changed in C99. However, it still applies to variables with static storage duration, so my memory wasn't completely off. (Also, I use C89/C90, C99 and C11 compilers)

Answer (score 0):

`ss` is an array of type `abc`, which you are trying to assign to variable `c` of type `abc`.

In other words, you are doing somewhat similar to

```
abc c;
abc ss[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
c = ss;
```

Change your `struct xyz` as follows:

```
typedef struct{
abc *c;
}xyz;
```

Now you can access the variables.

Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
int a;
int b;
int c;
}abc;

typedef struct{
abc *c;
}xyz;

int main()
{
abc ss[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
xyz cc[] = {ss};

int x = cc[0].c[1].b;

printf("%d", x);

return 0;
}
```